# How do I apply a simple armature that I made to a model?

Tags: armature

I have a simple model that I want to animate for a short film. How do I attach an armature to a model? I want to be able to move the armature, which will control the model, and pose the model for animation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In *object mode* right click the model than right click the armature with <kbd>Shift</kbd> after selecting both the model and the armature set the parent by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd> and choose the option *with automatic weights*.

[image: object-mode]

<sup>object mode</sup>

Finally you can change the armature in pose mode and the model will deform.

[image]

<sup>object mode</sup>

To change the weights (how much a region of the model is influenced by the position of a particular bone) you can enter the *weight paint mode* and use the brushes to assign different weights.

For rigging a human character you should learn about Rigify which must be enabled in the *user preferences / addons section*.

[image]

<sup>weight paint  mode</sup>

Comment: Where can I find the "Weight paint mode". I only see Object/Edit/Pose modes while selecting armatures.

Comment: @adelriosantiago Select the model in object mode