# Rotate posed character around the Z axis without deformation

Tags: animation

Hello Blender Stack Exchange, please be kind to an absolute newbie.

I've rigged a very basic character and managed to move him in pose mode and insert keyframes to make him walk along a scene, but I now want him to turn around. Rotating the armature deforms him horribly, making him really flat and wide. Switching into object mode and rotating him applies the rotation to every keyframe in the animation, grr.

How can I rotate my character around his own centre in pose mode or otherwise do a rotation in an animation?

**EDIT:**

Dropbox [link to my .blend file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8752722/HaighCharacter.blend) - excuse the goofiness, it's a video I'm trying to make for my mate Haighstrom.

Comment: Hi Mr. Pie :). Welcome to the site. Can you upload the blend file so we can take a look at it to better assist you. From your description, there are several things that could be wrong here.

Comment: Thanks, I can't work out how to post the blend file directly, so I'm editing in a dropbox link to it. I'm sure I've done all sorts of things wrong, it's my first ever mesh.

Comment: Your object centers are all over the place. It would be best to isolate the character into a separate file or layer, clear all relationships and settings, reset the object centers to normal and then rig it again. It seems you moved the character and its rig in both edit and pose mode several times before you animated it. I will try and see if it can be fixed while keeping the animation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you have moved the center of the mesh and the rig several times *(while in edit and pose mode)*. This is a big no no and would have brought about even more problems if you had continued on to do more complex transforms/animation etc.

---

***TL;DR:*** Clear all your object's transforms, and update the origin points for the rig and the model.

---

To fix.

1. Select the character and the rig and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to hide the rest of the scene so as to work without any distractions.
2. Select the character *HaighMan* and clear all transforms, Rotation <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, Location <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and Scale <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>.
3. Select the *entire* rig, which is currently in *pose mode* with <kbd>A</kbd> and repeat the previous steps for clearing all transforms.
4. Still selecting the rig, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to go to *object mode* and repeat the steps again for clearing transforms.

   Providing you followed the steps above, your scene should now look something like this.

   [image]
5. Select the rig and <kbd>Tab</kbd> into edit mode and adjust it to fit the model, select the root bone and use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected* and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> > *Origin to 3D Cursor*. You can then select the rig in *object mode* and rotate the character `90°` on the `Y` axis to have it stand upright.

   [image]
6. All should be well now, it is fixed but still broken as your previous animation keyframes are still on the armature. I would highly recommend clearing these and animating it again and also re-applying the model to the armature. If you now hit play, it will jump to the keyframed location and the character will start walking, you are now also able to rotate and scale each bone without any weird deformations.

More reading:

- [Weird Armature Deformation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2672/12)
- [How do I apply a simple armature that I made to a model?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/125/12)
- [How can I automatically generate vertex groups for an armature?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/782/12)