# Pulling armature from hierarchy?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones

So i'm new to rigging... or attempting to rig in blender and I seemed to have somehow created a hierarchy for my armature including it, and its poses. I cannot delete the poses, I cannot remove the armature from its grouping. For some reason I cannot apply my group to my model via parenting like I've been doing and I'd rather not remake the rig. Any help? If further explanation is needed please just say so- again i'm new so i'm not sure i'm using proper terms or just speaking gibberish.

Edit: Image of question added

Edit 2: I mean, if it can work this way that's fine too. I can't seem to get the armature to be applied to the model with automatic weights this way though.

[image]

Comment: could you post some pictures? It is hard to understand exactly what is being asked.

Comment: Heres an image, I dont quite see how to edit original post but Ill keep looking for it. http://i.gyazo.com/7b318e881420c8565051093189c32d8d.png

Comment: You can remove the weights and re - apply them i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every armature looks like that in the outliner. An armature is a little different from other objects - the bones show up twice, the `Armature` item holds the bone data used in edit mode, while the `Pose` data is what you animate in pose mode.

To deform a character mesh with an armature ensure you have selected your mesh and your armature and that your armature is the active object, that is the one that is highlighted in yellow rather than orange (if your armature is in pose mode it will be blue if it is active) [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/144/935) includes pictures. Automatic weights will only work if the armature is positioned within the mesh.

If you do have trouble setting up the armature you can also add an armature modifier to the mesh object and setup vertex weights using [weight painting](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Vertex_Groups/Weight_Paint) or manually [assigning weights](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Vertex_Groups/Vertex_Groups) to a selection of vertices.

Comment: When I apply the mesh to the armature as parent even when automatic weighting it doesnt seem to do any automatic weights. I guess i'll just have to apply them manually then. Thank you though!

Comment: You could also try adjusting [envelope weights](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Rigging/Armatures/Editing/Properties#Scaling_Specificities_in_B-Bone_and_Envelope_visualization) and parent with envelope weights, could give you a head start with weight painting.