# Is there any way to animate specific vertices instead of the whole object?

Tags: animation, mesh, vertices

I'm starting to do my first form of ***(somewhat)*** major animation in blender, before I've only done things like keyframes on text extrude, object size movement, etc. I want to warp an object in a specific sort, but I've tried creating keyframes on vector positions, and it doesn't seem to work! Is there any way to animate specific vertices instead of the whole object? Thanks!

Comment: Look into Shape Keys: https://www.blender.org/manual/animation/shape_keys/introduction.html

Comment: Take a look at the answer in http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70151/how-to-animate-a-beating-heart . It shows how weights are used to animate part of the mesh.

Answer (score 2):

To do this you need to create shapekeys and then keyframe their influence/strength.

Shapekeys are essentially alternative shapes for you mesh that allow you to interpolate between them and the base shape of the mesh.

see [the blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/shape_keys/index.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of animating hook objects to control specific vertices when you do not want to create a whole shape key setup, or are looking to use noise to generate random positions, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Use this [addon](https://blender-addons.org/animall-addon/). Enables animating almost everything.

Comment: I think it makes sense to recommend a beginner to learn all the basic native functionality of animation first before recommending any addons. Especially in this case since there are so many basic solutions for this - shapekeys, armatures, modifiers... I think the addon you are recommending is amazing, but this is not a good answer and bad advice for this context. At least it should be explained that this is in addition to all the basic functionality that can do this without the addon.

Comment: I disagree, it's exactly what he wanted and since he mentioned that he already knew the basic principles of keyframe animations this is the right advice for him. But I understand what you mean. Nevertheless I still think that this addon has to be mentioned here. Plus this addon is accessible through Blender interface so it's not just some untested addon that nobody knows.

Comment: A beginner reading this might get an impression that one needs an addon to animate a part of a mesh and it cannot be done other way conveniently. That would be very misleading since most standard every-day tools of animation are used for that. Armatures, modifiers and shapekeys can be used for that without any problems. Those are very common, powerful, flexible and robust tools suitable for many situations. No need to overcomplicate things from the start. The addon could be mentioned *in addition* to the common ways of doing it.

Comment: Well yea but all those other approaches are more like workarounds. But I get your point!