# I want to make the muscles pump like a heart (Resident Evil 4 Final Monster)

Tags: animation, physics, soft-body

I want the muscles of the legs pumping and have translucent properties so to show something is pumping inside. I know I can do soft body or cloth sim but I'm not sure how. I don't know how to pump it after that softness.

[image]

I want these marked areas to pump and act like flesh in my scene. I have one year of experience in Blender but still don't know many things so please suggest tips that are beginner-friendly.

The look I'm inspired from is this:
[image]

Comment: You could add bones that scale up and down to give the effect.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70151/how-to-animate-a-beating-heart

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do it using shape keys:

[Blender Character Animation: Shape Keys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YDu6y_2jFg0)